# find matches in two file using python

Tags: python, match

I am  analyzing sequencing data and I have few candidates genes that I need to find their functions.

After editing the available human database , I want to compare my candidate genes with the database and output the function for my candidate gene.

I have only basic python skills so I thought this might help me to speed up my work finding the functions of my candidate genes.

so file1 which contains the candidate genes look like this

```
Gene
AQP7
RLIM
SMCO3
COASY
HSPA6
```

and the database,file2.csv looks like this:

```
Gene   function 
PDCD6  Programmed cell death protein 6 
CDC2   Cell division cycle 2, G1 to S and G2 to M, isoform CRA_a 
CDC2   Cell division cycle 2, G1 to S and G2 to M, isoform CRA_a 
CDC2   Cell division cycle 2, G1 to S and G2 to M, isoform CRA_a 
CDC2   Cell division cycle 2, G1 to S and G2 to M, isoform CRA_a
```

desired output

```
 Gene(from file1) ,function(matching from file2)
```

i tried to use this code :

```
file1 = 'file1.csv'
file2 = 'file2.csv'
output = 'file3.txt'

with open(file1) as inf:
    match = set(line.strip() for line in inf)

with open(file2) as inf, open(output, 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if line.split(' ',1)[0] in match:
            outf.write(line)
```

I only get blank page.

I tried using intersection function

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as ref:
    with open('file2.csv','r') as com:
       with open('common_genes_function','w') as output:
           same = set(ref).intersection(com)
                print same
```

not working also..

Please help otherwise I need to do this manually

Comment: Did you try looking into python's `csv` module ? It has a lot of methods to hep parse csv files easily. You could probably load both the genes from `file1` into an array and then match each item of the array with the data loaded into memory by the csv module.

Comment: How do you relate the gene in the file1 to the function in the file2? Are CDC2 and PDCD genes availables in the file1?

Comment: genes in file1 should present in file2 as file2 is the complete human database . The data shown above are only part of the content .

Comment: In `file2.csv`, does each gene have a unique function?

Comment: some are repetitives as they  differ in other categories but i have removed other categories as I only need the function. That's why you can see repetitive genes in above example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `pandas` `merge` function. However, it requires a clear separator between the 'Gene' and 'function'-column. In my example, I assume it is at tab:

```
import pandas as pd
#open files as pandas datasets
file1 = pd.read_csv(filepath1, sep = '\t')
file2 = pd.read_csv(filepath2, sep = '\t')

#merge files by column 'Gene' using 'inner', so it comes up
#with the intersection of both datasets
file3 = pd.merge(file1, file2, how = 'inner', on = ['Gene'], suffixes = ['1','2'])
file3.to_csv(filepath3, sep = ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using basic Python, you can try the following:

```
import re

gene_function = {}
with open('file2.csv','r') as input:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in input.readlines()[1:]]
    for line in lines:
        match = re.search("(\w+)\s+(.*)",line)
        gene = match.group(1)
        function = match.group(2)
        if gene not in gene_function:
            gene_function[gene] = function

with open('file1.csv','r') as input:
    genes = [i.strip() for i in input.readlines()[1:]]
    for gene in genes:
        if gene in gene_function:
            print "{}, {}".format(gene, gene_function[gene])
```